# Ignoring empty cells while sorting table rows using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am trying to sort the table rows without any plugin. Unfortunately I don't have an option to use a plugin. Well here's what I have tried till now:

```
var info = $('#project_table tr.punch_list_summary');
    //For Closed Date
    $(document).on('click', '#descending_closed_date', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sortDir = -1;
        info.sort(function(a, b) {
            if ($(a).attr('data-closeddate') === 'null') {
                if ($(b).attr('data-closeddate') === 'null') {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            a = new Date($(a).attr('data-closeddate'));
            b = new Date($(b).attr('data-closeddate'));
            return (a - b) * sortDir;
        });
        $('#project_table').html(info);
        sortDir = 1;
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#ascending_closed_date', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sortDir = 1;
        info.sort(function(a, b) {
            if ($(a).attr('data-closeddate') === 'null') {
                if ($(b).attr('data-closeddate') === 'null') {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            a = new Date($(a).attr('data-closeddate'));
            b = new Date($(b).attr('data-closeddate'));
            return (a - b) * sortDir;
        });
        $('#project_table').html(info);
        sortDir = -1;
    });

});
```

As you can see I am using `data-attribute` to sort the rows. The **Closed Date** column can be empty or can have a date. The issue is it just sorts random rows, moreover, I am trying to bring all empty rows at the bottom and the rows with Closed Date at the top. What I might be doing wrong?

Here's the working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nalomuje/12/edit) for those who want to see what I have done till now. I would really appreciate any help.

**UPDATE**

Here's an updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nalomuje/18/edit). I can sort by closed date now but it still doesn't force the rows with empty closed dates to bottom.

Comment: What is not working? Sorting by closed date works fine

Comment: @juvian Well, I want to bring the rows with closed date up and the empty ones down & then sort them.

Comment: I would not expect all browsers to correctly parse date strings in the format `new Date('Apr 25 2014');`, the result in some will be `NaN`. Consider using a [time value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) instead.

Comment: So what I should do instead?

Comment: BTW, an advantage of using a time value is that they can be sorted directly as numbers, there's no need to convert them to a date string (though that is fairly easy if required for human readable display).

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use Dates like that. :(

Comment: BTW I am getting this error now, Uncaught TypeError: Object Apr 25 2014 has no method 'getTime'.

Comment: I agree with @RobG. BTW you can convert the date string into another format, for example unix epoch date: d = new Date('Feb 24 2014').getTime() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods

Comment: When I do that I get, "Uncaught TypeError: Object Apr 25 2014 has no method 'getTime'".

Comment: When I copy/paste this directly into the console it works for me: new Date('Feb 24 2014').getTime(); returns 1393218000000

Comment: Using your date of Apr 24 2014 I get 1398398400000

Comment: Even though I converting to to time, I am still not able to get expected result. I want to bring the rows with Closed Dates to up and then sort them. Furthermore, rows with empty closed dates should be down.

Comment: You will get different values depending on the time zone (if it's parsed correctly at all). If you want a consistent time value, do: `new Date(Date.UTC(...))` so the string is treated as UTC. But then the dislpayed string will be different depending on the timezone. But that should be irrelevant if all you are using the value for is to sort as it will be consistent within the same timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If descending and the data is "null", make the data as 1 Jan 1900 (so it will be at the bottom)
If ascending and the data is "null", make the data as 1 Jan 9999 (so it will be at the bottom)

Then do a normal comparison y-x or x-y.

http://jsbin.com/nalomuje/23/edit